# Difference between state management and session management?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following are the commonly used state management techniques.

```
QueryString
Cookies
Cache
ViewState
Session state(eg: Session[“name”])
Application state
Static variables
Profiles
```

Are session state (e.g. `Session [“name”]`) and session management the same?

InProc, State Server and SQLServer mode: are these related to session state or session management?

State management and session management in ASP.NET are the same or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> InProc, State Server and SQLServer mode

This just determines *where* your session state is stored.

**Resources**

- [ASP.NET Session State
  Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [ASP.NET State Management
  Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.ASPX)
- [Session-State
  Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.ASPX)

Comment: Difference between state management and session management in asp.net?

Comment: Is there a question in that comment? If you don't understand my answer, please point out a specific issue, don't just repeat your question. _"State management"_ is the broader picture (click the "ASP.NET State Management Overview" link in my answer for details), while sessions are a specific form of state management, and "session management" determines where your session data is stored.

Comment: @InProc, State Server and SQLServer mode related only to Session?

Comment: Blue text are links. Click them. Read. Learn. See my updated answer. To answer that question: those are Session-State Modes, so yes, they are only related to **where your session state is stored**.

Comment: I have attended an interview and one of the interviewers asked me about session management. I started with session state (eg: Session [“name”],InProc, State Server and SQLServer mode).But they repeated that they are asking about session management. Thus I got confused with the terms.

Comment: @anish well, "session management" isn't really a term you'll find strictly defined in an ASP.NET context. See [Google: "session management" "asp.net" site:msdn.microsoft.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22session%20management%22%20asp.net%20site:msdn.microsoft.com). Did you just ask your interviewers what they meant? Perhaps they meant _"state management"_, of which _"session"_ is one example.

Answer (score 1):

state management and session management  are different, state management is made with viewstate, by default Web is stateless, but with Viewstate you can save data when you post, it's also used in order persist data with minimal code. for example for persisting dropdownlist you don't need bind data every time tou post.

but session is made with Session property of your context. she can be stored on your process, or on server hosted or in sql server.

Cache and Application are global cache in order share datas between differents sessions.

Cookies it's stored on your client

Profiles is dedicated for security need

Answer (score 0):

Client-side state management:
In some scenarios, it reduces network traffic and/or simplifies your client application, because you are not doing roundtrips
Generally, you can store less data than if you used the server side approach
You have less control over the integrity and consistency of the state, due to the environment where you're saving it (the client)
State is confined to a computer, cannot follow the user
Server-side:
Needs roundtrips to the server and the complexities that come with those
You have more control: what, where, how long you keep it
Can follow the user accross system boundaries
You have to decide what's better for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

state management and session management are different

[Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management)

Answer (score 0):

Web is Stateless. It means a new instance of the web page class is re-created each time the page is posted to the server. As we all know HTTP is a stateless protocol, its can't holds the client information on page. As for example , if we enter a text and client on submit button, text does not appear after post back , only because of page is recreated on its round trip.

As given in above pages, page is recreated before its comes to clients and happened for each and every request. So it is a big issue to maintain the state of the page and information for a web application. That is the reason to start concept of State Management. To overcome this problem ASP.NET 2.0 Provides some features like View State, Cookies, Session, Application objects etc. to manage the state of page.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State